# Restore workspace on branch switching not working

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm working on three main branches (*develop*, *release*, *master*) in IntelliJ 2020.3 using Git and the option **Restore workspace on branch switching** is checked (under *Version Control* > *Confirmation*).

When I switch to *release* or *master*, from any other branch, the workspace is correctly restored, however, when switching to *develop*, it never works and the opened files are kept opened (workspace is not updated).

Any hint on this?

Comment: is there a chance that you are using the task feature?
Have you committed "workspace.xml" by any chance in?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I'm using YouTrack. Could that be the reason of the problem? Btw, workspace.xml is ignored in git.

Comment: So you are using YouTrack as a task server, is it correct? Are those branches have dedicated task?
Even if the file is in .gitignore it is worth checking whether it has been committed before. Perhaps it's committed in one of branches.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me: try to restart IntelliJ with **Invalidate Caches**